# I would like to know what this word means

Tags: словоупотребление

I was sent a message. I could translate all of it except for this word: прилогаю

Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's "прилагаю" (I attach) written with an error.

Answer (score 6):

"Прилагать" means *to attach*, to add something, give more information. (Alex is right, there's a spelling typo).